# Java LibGDX Box2D lighting bug

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, lighting, box2dlights

I have recently started a tile based game. So far so good, I implemented Box2D and added rigid bodies for the tiles. Then I added Box2D Lights. This is where the problem arose. This is a screenshot of the issue:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2eBw.png).

As you can see half the screen is rendered, and the other half is not, although the shadows are still created by the bodies. This is definitely a problem with Box2D lights, because if I disable them the problem disappears. As far as I can see Box2D lights decides to stop some textures from being rendered, probably because it thinks that they are off screen.

**My Question is, does anyone know what this is or how to solve it? I believe that this is a bug, and if anyone knows more help would be appreciated!**

My light rendering code is as follows

```
// Game stuff is rendered here. This part works fine.

// ...

// Render lights
rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(PixelEngineers.camera);
rayHandler.updateAndRender();
```

Comment: By the way I have tried to disable culling in rayhandler. Did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, my fault, solved this by rendering the lights AFTER the batch had been ended.
// Game stuff is rendered here. This part works fine.

// ...

batch.end()

// Render lights
rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(PixelEngineers.camera);
rayHandler.updateAndRender();   `

Comment: [Select isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips)